# Does index can affect update?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

I have a table with one million rows. I am trying to update a specific column based on the value from the other column.

```
update m
set repname = e.LastName + ', ' + e.FirstName, 
    empNo = i.empNo,
    DateHired = e.DateHired, 
    DateTerminated = e.DateTerminated,  
    TeamCode = e.TeamCode
from 
    nyox m
inner join 
    nyerk e on m.orderSplitRepNumber = e.EmployeeNumber
inner join 
    choks i on  (m.orderSplitRepNumber) = i.full_empNo
```

Would it be faster if I create index on nyox on the column with a relationship on other table?

```
CREATE Nonclustered INDEX ix_orderSplitRepNumber
ON nyox (orderSplitRepNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be faster if I create index on nyox on the column with a relationship on other table?

It depends on how many row's *don't* have matching rows in the related tables.  If most rows have related records, the optimizer may decide that a table scan would perform just as well, so an index wouldn't make any difference.

Indexes on `nyerk.EmployeeNumber` and `choks.full_empNo`, however, *would* likely make the update faster.

Answer (score 0):

test with this
clearly indexes on joins will help
but locks and set are going to dominate that update

```
select m.orderSplitRepNumber, 
       e.LastName,
       e.FirstName, 
       i.empNo,
       e.DateHired, 
       e.DateTerminated,  
       e.TeamCode
  from nyox m
  join nyerk e 
    on m.orderSplitRepNumber = e.EmployeeNumber
  join choks i 
    on m.orderSplitRepNumber = i.full_empNo
```

Is there a chance it already has the values?
Taking the write lock is the expensive part.
If you use the top clause then you will need to loop but at 1 million you may fill up a transaction log.
with (nolock) is optional and only if you know it is safe

```
update top (10000) m
   set m.repname = e.LastName + ', ' + e.FirstName, 
       m.empNo = i.empNo,
       m.DateHired = e.DateHired, 
       m.DateTerminated = e.DateTerminated,  
       m.TeamCode = e.TeamCode
  from nyox m
  join nyerk e with (nolock)
    on m.orderSplitRepNumber = e.EmployeeNumber
  join choks i with (nolock) 
    on m.orderSplitRepNumber = i.full_empNo
 where m.repname <> e.LastName + ', ' + e.FirstName, 
   and m.empNo <> i.empNo,
   and m.DateHired <> e.DateHired, 
   and m.DateTerminated <> e.DateTerminated,  
   and m.TeamCode <> e.TeamCode
```